# Can't visualize appropiately RStudio Notebooks

Tags: rstudio

[See strange behavior in this youtube video](https://youtu.be/T9fu5bZhTB8)

Most of the time I have issues visualizing the preview inline in Rstudio notebook. The problem is that the output of the chunks remains fixed in the screen.

I didnt change the configuration.

Is this a bug or is normal for rstudio notebook?

Additional info
    R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

```
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tables_0.7.79   Hmisc_4.0-0     Formula_1.2-1   survival_2.40-1  lattice_0.20-33 lubridate_1.5.6 dplyr_0.5.0     purrr_0.2.2     readr_0.2.2    
[10] tidyr_0.6.0     tibble_1.2      ggplot2_2.1.0   tidyverse_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.5         formatR_1.4         RColorBrewer_1.1-2  plyr_1.8.4          base64enc_0.1-3     tools_3.2.3         rpart_4.1-10       
 [8] digest_0.6.9        jsonlite_0.9.22     evaluate_0.9        gtable_0.2.0        htmlTable_1.7       Matrix_1.2-6        DBI_0.4-1          
[15] yaml_2.1.13         gridExtra_2.2.1     stringr_1.0.0       knitr_1.14          cluster_2.0.4       grid_3.2.3          nnet_7.3-12        
[22] data.table_1.9.6    R6_2.1.2            rmarkdown_1.1       foreign_0.8-66      latticeExtra_0.6-28 magrittr_1.5        scales_0.4.0       
[29] htmltools_0.3.5     splines_3.2.3       rsconnect_0.5       assertthat_0.1      colorspace_1.2-6    labeling_0.3        stringi_1.1.1      
[36] acepack_1.3-3.3     lazyeval_0.2.0      munsell_0.4.3       chron_2.3-47
```

Comment: What version of RStudio itself are you using? This is a bug which existed in older versions of the RStudio notebook, but you shouldn't see it any more. Can you try reproducing in the [RStudio Preview Release](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/)? If it still happens there, could you try recreating the problem in a blank notebook?

Comment: using RStudio Version 1.0.44 – © 2009-2016 RStudio, Inc.
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) rstudio Safari/538.1 Qt/5.4.1.